I have a bash script asking for input, but if that input is not in the correct format, I want to ask for it again. Not sure how without GOTO loop
I am writing a bash script that will ask for input (in this case, and IP address), but if the IP address is not in the correct format, I want to have it keep asking until the user types it correctly. What I am asking for is how to do a GOTO when bash does not have a GOTO command. What is the easiest way to do this?
The code I have is:
#!/bin/bash
# There will be additional code here that is not relevant to this question.
# Ask for IPv4 address
echo    Please type the IPv4 address of the host:
read ipv4addr
if [[ $ipv4addr =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
  # do something
else
  echo "The IP address is not in the correct format. Please try again."
  # I need to have it go back to #Ask for the IPv4 address  
fi


There s no mention of ANY version of Ubuntu being used in this question.

@DavidDE, It is Ubuntu 24.04

Please edit the question and add that. Comments often go away.

Note that while it is true that anything that fails to match your bash regular expression cannot be a valid IPv4 address, not everything that does match it is. If you truly want to validate an IPv4 address, some better options are:

Perl's Regexp::Common::net (also its Ubuntu manpage)
this newer Perl module Data::Validate::IP

See also grep regular expression that matches all valid IPv4 and IPv6 addresses

In order to do something until a test succeeds, you can use one of the shell's Looping Constructs - for example, a while loop:
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
  read -p "Please type the IPv4 address of the host: " ipv4addr
  if [[ $ipv4addr =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    break
  else
    echo "The IP address is not in the correct format. Please try again."
  fi
done

# do something


Note that this code will accept the invalid IPv4 address 999.999.999.999.

Also 0.0.0.0 and 127.x.x.x ? Or any reserved address for that matter such as 10.255.255.255

@DavidDE yes there are more matches that are not valid IP addresses than are - however that did not seem to be the focus of the question. Reliably matching IP addresses is harder than it sounds - see for example grep regular expression that matches all valid IPv4 and IPv6 addresses

Yes I taught this stuff for over 15 years.

@DavidDE it's really not my area of expertise but I have added a note which I hope clarifies things

My comment was based on the OP implies he expected the user to be connected to something after entering the correct IP.

For what I needed, it was to add a DNS record to the Bind9 zone files, and more so that if I fat-finger when typing the address, it doesn't add it to the zone files. I hate having to try to remember where the files are saved each time I need to add to the zone files, so I decided to create a script for adding a new host. I don't need it to check if the address is a valid address, just that it is the correct format.

Doesn't matter much but the regexp could be a bit more concise - ^([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+$

Since you'd want to prompt for input until a valid input is received, consider using an until loop:
until
  echo Please type the IPv4 address of the host:
  read ipv4addr
  [[ $ipv4addr =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]
do
  echo "The IP address is not in the correct format. Please try again."
done
# Do the "something" here.


I found that I could use a function to do what I wanted.
#!/bin/bash
function readipv4addr()
{
echo    Please type the IPv4 address of the host\:
read ipv4addr
echo    The FQDN is\: $fqdnhost
if [[ $ipv4addr =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
  domain=${fqdnhost#*.}
# do something.
else
  echo "The IP address is not in the correct format. Please try again."
readipv4addr  # loops back to beginning of function here.
fi
}

# begin execution of script


You should parse each octet, and ensure it fits into 8 bits (0-255). The "address" field in the packet header is 32 bits, expressed as 4 octets.

Regarding "loops back to beginning of function here" - that's not a loop, it's a recursive call. Don't do that as it sucks up resources unnecessarily, just write a loop. You have a few other issues in that script, copy/paste it into http://shellcheck.net to learn about and fix some of them.
